# Java how to split an unknown length String with dash and return all combinations

Tags: java, regex, string, jakarta-ee

How can I split a java string into two parts by dash and return all combinations?

For example, I will get a string always coming with

"aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-..." format.

I want to clean way to split this string into the following two strings.

```
"aa" "bb-cc-dd-ee-..."
"aa-bb" "cc-dd-ee-..."
"aa-bb-cc" "dd-ee-..."
"aa-bb-cc-dd" "ee-..."
"aa-bb-cc-dd-ee" "..."
```

...
and return all combinations.

I need to find a clean way to do this.

Comment: Why fast way? Have you derived the slowest way to solve this?

Comment: 1) I doubt this needs to be the real fast, otherwise you wouldn't be asking here.
2) Split for the dash and then build each combination again (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: I was using string split with dash and then get string [] back, and iterat through array to combine the substrings, and then add all substirngs into array and send back, but code looks like ugly. I might be asking what is the clean way to do this.

Comment: Or don't use regex at all, as it doesn't directly yield the desired solution.  This looks like more of a job for `String.indexOf()` and `String.subString()`.

Comment: @YiLiu Kindly in future, post the code that you have, to avoid this kind of downvotes on your question.

Comment: @RohitJain, thanks for your kindly reminding. I was thinking I should keep my question short to make it easier to read. my existing code is too long, I am afraid to post here to make people more confuse.

Comment: @YiLiu You can always filter out the necessary block of code, and post here. And no need to be afraid to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting your string via a regex will be a bit messy, because what you ultimately want is pieces corresponding to *different* splits.  You can split more finely and then reconstitute the pieces, but I'm inclined to think that the cleanest way to do this is the old-school way, by searching the string for the delimiter and splitting manually.  For example, this will do what you want, as I understand it:

```
public String[] splitString(String s) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    int start = 0;

    while (true) {
        int next = s.indexOf('-', start);

        if (next < 0) {
            break;
        }
        results.add(s.subString(0, next));
        results.add(s.subString(next + 1));
        start = next + 1;
    }

    return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. This one is much clean than mine. Code looks very comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the current answers, I would go about this in a very different way:

First, we want a small class to keep our answers clean:

```
public class Partition {
    private final String left;
    private final String right;

    public Partition(String left, String right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return left + " " + right;
    }
}
```

Then, we can keep the actual code extremly terse:

```
public static List<Partition> splitString(String s) {
    List<Partition> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            results.add(new Partition(s.substring(0, i), s.substring(i + 1)));
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

This is easy to read, and easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Quick 'n dirty.  (but maybe not quick enough?)

```
   String inputString = "aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff-gg";
    String pieces[] = inputString.split("-");
    System.out.println("pieces.length " + pieces.length);
    for (int i=0;i<pieces.length-2; i++) {
        StringBuffer firstString = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer secondString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
            firstString.append(pieces[j]);
            if (j<i) {
                firstString.append("-");
            }
        }
        for (int j=i+1; j<pieces.length; j++) {
            if (j>i+1) {
                secondString.append("-");
            }
            secondString.append(pieces[j]);
        }
        System.out.println(firstString + "   " + secondString);
    }
```

Comment: Thx for the help. this one is better than mine but I more like John Bollinger's code, looks clean to me.